# What questions should be definitely off-topic?

Tags: discussion, faq, questions, scope

Obviously questions not about Blender would be off-topic but what should be the general yardstick for off-topicness?

## Update:

Since the site has [moderators](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165/moderator-pro-tem-announcement) now and we can better address on/off-topicness, we feel it is time to start rolling out some of these to our **[help page](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help)** where needed. This is so we can have *one* definite place to point new users to.. etc.

It is also worth noting that none of these were thought up by any *one* person. These were decided to be the norm and are only here because of them being agreed upon by the majority. Poke around meta or browse through the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag to find these.

Comment: Shouldn't this have been determined while still in [definition phase](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40377?phase=definition)?

Comment: It's still useful to have a place on Meta that you can point to.

Comment: @DantheMan You can still change/fix/improve the scope as you go. :)

Answer (score 36):

Per suggestions and discussions, those that should definitely be ***off-topic*** are:

---

1. Requests for tutorials and lengthy HOW-TO's<sup>1</sup>

   - Can anyone make a tutorial on doing X?
   - How can I animate a short film in Blender?
   - Please recommend links to tutorials.

---

2. Package or software comparison questions

   - Which is better for doing X, Max or Blender?
   - Which is better for animating for games, Maya or Blender?

---

3. Hardware specifications, recommendations, reviews or faults

   - What is the best processor to run Blender on?
   - Why does my new graphics card run Cycles 10% slower then my old card?
   - How can I prevent my system overheating while rendering?
   - Should I buy  $X$ or  $Y$ GPU, what do you recomend?

---

4. Developing Blender (in C/C++), *Python scripting is fine*

   - How can I add a new editor type like *Tracking* to Blender using C?
   - How do I code with C++ in Blender?

---

5. Feature requests or localized technical questions

   - When will Blender get brushes like those in zBrush?
   - How can I port Blender from OpenGL to DirectX?

---

6. Critique and Showcasing

   - Does my model look OK?
   - How can I model *this* object better?
   - Has anyone used blender to 3D print? I would love to see examples!

---

7. General 3D resources (aka not blender specific)

   - What is a good place to buy 3D models?
   - What is the most common file type?

---

8. Questions about *other* Blender websites excluding the wiki & manual.

   - How do I submit an article to BlenderNation?
   - Where do I find X on the main Blender website?

---

9. Support requests

   - If a blend file's required to ***answer*** the question, it's generally not a valid question and belongs in a support forum like [blenderartists](http://blenderartists.org/forum/).

---

10. Bugs

    - These should instead be [reported to the tracker](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Bug_Reports). See [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports/1378#1378) for more information.

---

11. Job Offers of Requests

    - Can someone do ____ for me? (Paid or Unpaid).
    - I'm looking for work (Paid or unpaid).

    This kind of requests can be done on [blenderartists.org](https://blenderartists.org/c/jobs). There are forums for paid and volunteer work.

---

12. Licensing and copyright issues

    - Licensing a game
    - Use of trademarks or copyrighted models or images.

    Use: https://law.stackexchange.com/ instead

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>This has caused quite some commotion, I clarify what I mean in [Regarding questions and answers as tutorials](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62/regarding-questions-and-answers-as-tutorials)</sub>

Comment: I'd add Hardware to that list as well.

Comment: Could you add: Developing Blender (the application - C,C++), this doesn't include python scripting.

Comment: Does changing the question to `How can I add a new editor type like Tracking to Blender using python?` make it ok?

Comment: @greatwolf technically as stated above, *yes*, since python can be used to add gui elements it could be a valid one even though it would not be plausible and would be accordingly dealt with

Comment: I guess the question I'm trying to raise is what makes python any more appropriate to ask than C or C++ because technically writing python scripts is a form of blender development.

Comment: @greatwolf see my last response, python is used in the development of Blender, it can be used for several purposes such as adding GUI elements and as such could be valid. Another reason is C/C++ would stray too far from actual Blender and more into low level stuff and os related complexities. Python is used extensively in Blender and is a main part of it. So as I initially said, depending on how it is worded, it *could* be valid but would not be plausible or at least get a definitive response if used as it is in the example above.

Comment: Questions like "Does this render look cool?" or any sort of "Rate my model"-type questions.

Comment: I suggest we take some more time before we begin jumping on questions that appear to fit this criteria. We need time to define, though we must be relatively stringent of course.

Comment: Questions regarding hotkeys. These are easily available by a quick google search, or can be simply asked in the chat.

Comment: Should questions about building development builds be off topic?: Eg, How can I build Branch `foo` on github url `bar`, I tried but I got error message `baz`. .... closely related, should questions about running development branches be off topic? (GSOC work in progress branches for example).

Comment: @ideasman42 GSOC yes and building to some extent but we can't take any error messages *(or at least any overly complicated ones like pasteall dumps)*, remember there can only be so much wrong on a users end and the site is not really a debugging/error-finding service per say.. if a question is deemed too technical it can and will be addressed accordingly.

Comment: I don't want to be too strict about hotkey questions, because I worry that we'll become newbie-bashers. There are already a lot of good questions about "the best way to do X" where there is more than one "hotkey" answer. The rest of this list seems fine. *nod*

Comment: Back to building blender being off-topic, This is a question about building an experimental feature. Check the comments under the question and you can probably see why we might be best off considetring these questions off topic - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1574/using-blender-as-a-python-module

Comment: `Requests for tutorials` and `Lengthy or ridiculous how to requests` could be merged into one item IMHO, maybe `Requests for tutorials or lengtht HOW-TO's` ?

Comment: @ideasman42 perhaps a meta expanding on it as I have expanded on the tutorial request bit and feel free to edit the post.

Comment: @iKlsR What about asking for help in "community projects"?

Comment: Note, I wasn't sure if we should consider customized blender builds off topic - asked in separate Q.  http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/722/should-questions-about-customized-blender-mods-be-considered-off-topic

Comment: So, if questions about hot keys are off topic, why is there a "hotkeys" tag? Or should the issue of questions about hot keys be reconsidered?

Comment: @brasshat Granted this was over two years ago, the scope of what is allowed has been changed ever so slightly in some cases. After we get our design and or more mods it could change again. Made a note to update this.

Comment: Pirated content, e.g. "ripped game models", also templates, that need the original author's permission to be modified, should also be on this list.

Comment: After reading this (just now) and the comments, I find the wording in #4 unclear. Is it that C/C++ questions are not okay and Python questions are? If that's the case, would adding something to the part in italics be possible to clarify? Such as putting it in parenthesis and writing: (This does not apply to questions about Python scripting. Python scripting is on topic.)

Answer (score 10):

In my opinion, a concrete question about Blender whose answer is not immediate to everyone who cares and which can be answered objectively by a post of reasonable length should be accepted here.  If a post is too vague, not a question, not about Blender, immediately answerable by everyone who cares, cannot be answered objectively, or cannot be answered in a reasonable length, then it is off-topic.

I do not agree with the list.  (A question about software comparison is bad only if it is vague or subjective.  “Why does my new graphics card run Cycles 10% slower than my old card?” is not a question about hardware specifications or reviews, but a question about Blender which requires knowledge about hardware.  A question about development of Blender is a question about Blender.  A question about hotkeys is bad only if the answer is immediate to everyone who cares.  And I fail to see what is lengthy about [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129/how-to-do-a-cloth-simulation-in-blender) or its answer.)

More importantly, I fail to understand why we need a list like this at this early stage.  Let’s solve the problems we face instead of the problems we imagine.

Comment: With regard to the last point, I think it is important to [establish the boundaries of the site early](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/).

Comment: @grc: It is fine to ask “Is a question like this [something concrete] on-topic or off-topic?” as long as you can reasonably expect someone will ask it.  Asking for a list of  “definitely off-topic” questions is different from that.

Comment: A list of off-topic questions needs to be created for the FAQ. Discussion usually begins as early as the definition phase of Area 51. I don't see why we should wait for bad questions to be asked.

Comment: @grc: Because we cannot imagine what will be asked.  If _you_ want to ask something and wonder whether it is on-topic or off-topic, it is useful to discuss it.  But if you just imagine _someone might_ ask it, leave the decision until the problem becomes real, because whether it is on-topic or off-topic depends on the details of the actual question which we cannot imagine now.

Comment: @grc: FAQ stands for frequently asked questions.  If the site does not receive any off-topic questions during the public beta, we do not need the list of off-topic questions as FAQ.  But that will not happen in reality, so do not worry.

Comment: @YuAsakusa its been nearly 3 weeks already, much of this list was contributed to by several users based on actual questions we saw that didn't fit in the scope of what this site is or should be about. If we don't lay the foundation from now, what will happen when new users start running amok asking about scifi films and making games? This is *not* a forum per say and since most people are used to forum style discussions, it is a good idea to get this information out as quickly as possible and as grc points out, we *will* need a FAQ eventually.