# Beginner's Reference

Tags: discussion

## Update:

Since this post is less likely to be seen by visitors to the site and is technically not what meta is for (we were working on the kinks at the time), there is now a community maintained [wiki post on the main site](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender) listing many resources for blender. If you want to contribute to this, add your content there.

---

After going through [faq](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/faq) and seeing questions [What would be wrong with tutorials as long as they describe a reusable workflow?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29/what-would-be-wrong-with-tutorials-as-long-as-they-describe-a-reusable-workflow) and [What questions should be definitely off-topic?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic)

Two points are fairly clear:

- The site isn't a ground for tutorials
- People are going to come by asking for them

To help out on that, and to help more experienced users who still have what to learn, I propose building a page where links to documentation, references and tutorial are available. This would also make the site more welcoming, instead of just closing the question.

Another option, just linking to [blender.org/support/tutorials](http://www.blender.org/support/tutorials/).

Answer (score 17):

## Documentation

- [Manual 2.6](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual)
- [Blender Wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/)
- [Python API 2.6](http://www.blender.org/documentation/250PythonDoc)

## General Tutorials

- [Tutorials on official site](http://www.blender.org/education-help/tutorials/)
- [Noob to Pro](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro)
- [Blender Cookie](http://cgcookie.com/blender/) ([Jonathan Williamson](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/44/jonathan-williamson))
- [Blender Guru](http://www.blenderguru.com) ([Andrew Price](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/165/andrew-price))
- [Blender Nerd](http://www.blendernerd.com) ([Greg Zaal](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/9/greg-zaal))
- [Blender Diplom](http://www.blenderdiplom.com/en/tutorials/all-tutorials.html)
- [KatsBits Blender tutorials & Blender training](http://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/)
- [Blender Modifier Series](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLE8021F9820C6FB9C)
- [Spastic Kangaroo](http://www.youtube.com/thespastickangaroo) ([CharlesL](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/20/charlesl))
- [Blender Hints and Advice: A General Guide](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Teh_Bucket)

## Game Engine

- [Nilunder's BGE Request Branch](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLBF3FB2A571A6BB7C)
- [Detailed Reference of Logic Bricks](http://www.tutorialsforblender3d.com/)
- [Wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Tutorials/Game_Engine/Resources/BGE_Tutorials/Python_Tutorials) (python)

## Python

- [Python basic](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)
- [Scripting](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro#Unit_4:_Taking_Off_with_Advanced_Tutorials)
- [Wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Py/Scripts)
- [Blender Scripting blogspot](http://blenderscripting.blogspot.com)
- [Blender Sushi](http://blendersushi.blogspot.de/)
- [Addon tutorial](http://michelanders.blogspot.nl/p/creating-blender-26-python-add-on.html)

## Resources

- [Blend Swap](http://blendswap.com) - free blender meshes, materials, and whatnot
- [CG Textures](http://cgtextures.com) - free textures
- [List of resources on the main site](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15355/599)

## GLSL

- [GLSL 1.2 Tutorial](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/?intro)

## Misc

- [Blender Artist](http://blenderartists.org) - Blender forum to showcase and get feedback on Blender art.
- [Blender Nation](http://blendernation.com) - Hub for Blender news, resources and art showcases.
- [code.blender.org](http://code.blender.org/) - Blender development blog.
- [How should I get started if I want to work as a 3D designer for games?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19794/how-should-i-get-started-if-i-want-to-work-as-a-3d-designer-for-games) - A question on the Graphic Design Stack exchange about how to get started making 3D for games.

Comment: I've created a 21 part text based tutorial series for getting a completely new user up to speed to create 2D or 3D game assets in Blender that might be a good fit on your list. [Complete Blender Game Art tutorial for Beginners](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/page/Complete-Blender-Game-Art-Tutorial-From-zero-experience-to-2D-or-3D-game-ready-asset.aspx)

Comment: @stacker This was mainly a list of tutorial/training type resources (as opposed to asset resources), unless I'm missing something..

Comment: @gandalf3 agreed I rolled back, I going to start my own collection at zeef.com it would have been more useful if we had one collaborativly list.

Answer (score 9):

It is also common to put resources and tutorials relating to a specific topic in the tag wikis. Most of the popular tags on stackoverflow have quite comprehensive wikis (e.g. [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) or [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info)).

I'd love to see some useful links and information added to the tag wikis here, especially for common tags like [modeling](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modeling) or [rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rendering).

Comment: Nice suggestion, but half of the tags we currently have can barely fill the excerpt box. ;)

Comment: The site only launched yesterday :P