# Are questions about external tutorial/resources on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions asking for other resources on topic?

For instance:

- https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6950/599
- [non-video blender resources?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7049/599)
- [Resource for Blender addons?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1342/599)
- [Any good free materials libraries online?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5593/599)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would vote for having one community wiki question on each topic, and close duplicates.

Like:

- [Beginner's Reference](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40/beginners-reference) (on meta)
- [Any good free materials libraries online?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5593/any-good-free-materials-libraries-online).

This is even on SO stil on-topic see e.g. [the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: How specific should each topic be? Would "non-video tutorials" be to specific?

Comment: @gandalf3 I think the topics shouldn't overlap. I'm not sure about "non-video", could we add a column to each of the links in beginner's reference to indicate that it covers only video tutorials?

Answer (score 3):

I think if the question has potential benefit a majority of blender users. It should be allowed to ask even though it might not fit the format. An example of such a question would be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python this question has many userfull answers and is beneficial to a large group of users even though it is *it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site*

I think the question needs to be general so that many people can contribute.

- Any good free materials libraries online? there are really only a few - bad for the main site
- Useful resource for blender tutorials? there are plenty of sites, youtube channels, blogs, etc. - good