# Are questions about finding specific addons/other resources on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

There was a [question asked recently](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/10749/599), asking for help finding a certain addon.

Imo these types of questions might be more on the forum/discussion side of things to fit cleanly in a Q&A format, but it's arguable.

Are these "help me find this" questions on-topic?

---

Related: [Are questions about external tutorial/resources on topic?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/341/599)

Comment: Maybe chat would be useful for that.

Answer (score 2):

I would say yes, it seems like `blender.stackexchange.com` is here to answer questions relating to Blender. Is wondering about a certain addon or looking for a tutorial about something in Blender not related to Blender? I don't think so, I think that the forum should be here to help spur Blender users on, by answering any questions that they have. As long as they do relate to Blender.

Answer (score 1):

I use several StackExchange communities, coming back to them when the rest of the infosphere lets me down, due to two recurring attributes: 1) tagged searching and 2) permanence.   The free-form nature of forums is a valuable tool, sometimes, but in the Blender world I find a couple of problems crop up repeatedly that I don't see nearly as often in the StackExchange approach: First, Blender advances rapidly and the appropriateness of the answers discussed in forums ages rapidly. So having a question about how to do something in Blender 2.70 that uses terminology carried over from 2.4 may or may not be helpful.  Second, and this touches on your mention of external tutorials, I have found so many tutorial links that are dead links that I almost never follow such links anymore unless the URL starts with youtube ;-)

I enjoy reading related question/answers as pointed to by the StackExchange engine because learning can be unexpected and sometimes I find a question I can help answer.  But, I suspect, most people are trying to get to the answer as directly as potential answerers want a question to be specific.  Tagged searching has really helped with that.  I was surprised when I first posed a question on blender.stackexchange and tried to tag it with the version number I was using, only to be told such a tag didn't exist and I couldn't create it.  Arguments exist both ways, to be sure.  Having used the search feature at a very popular Blender forum site, I've been frustrated that a search term would match in a long-developed discussion, but with no clue as to where in the discussion the topic came up.  I learn a lot in reading 27 pages of a discussion but after a while the frustration at not having found the search term rises above the serendipitous rewards.

I wonder if there isn't a middle ground, somewhere between targeted questions and rambling forums?

(I do notice that your title is the same as your last sentence (question).  I'm probably not answering that very well!  I'm just trying to provide a perspective as a discussion point.)