# How about a recommended practices page?

Tags: discussion

Might there not be value to the community for something akin to the [Resources](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender) question where we assemble a list of answers providing "recommended practices" for the benefit of less experienced members of the community, especially when the best practices are not necessarily immediately obvious. One of the first "recommended practices" I would suggest should be on the page is to frequently apply scale and rotation. There are others that should be on such a list, too.

Comment: I'm not so sure about your idea. I'm sure that if we could get people to properly trouble-shoot their .blends before asking a question the quality of the site overall would rise, but having just another meta post for people to ignore isn't the way to do it.

Comment: The "Resources" page I reference in the question is on the main BSE site, not the "meta" one. And I would expect that trouble shooting might come into play on such a site in the case of something on the order of "when I see this condition in blender, this is the first thing I check". But what I propose is something broader than just a trouble shooting help.

Answer (score 6):

Please understand I don't have any real authority in saying this, but I don't believe another list of workflow tutorials would be necessary as both the [resources question you linked](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender) and the [beginner's reference question](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40/beginners-reference) already serve close to this exact purpose.

Comment: I agree. What we could do is find a way to better link it to newcomers.