# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderation

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: iKlsR]
[image: Dan the Man]
[image: Gwenn]
[image: RolandiXor]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections in several weeks.**
Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: Several weeks? Has graduation time been decided already? O.o (or is "several" supposed to mean "6-8"?)

Comment: @Manishearth the former could and might be possible since we are doing so well. ;)

Comment: @ikls  you may even beat Mathematica.SE for fastest launch! Good luck!

Comment: Yep I think we might out do our own expectations :)

Comment: Congrats new mods. Great to see you've stepped up

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. We already have 1000 views per day!

Comment: Great job folks. Great to have you leading the way. :)