# Are questions about modifying the source code allowed here?

Tags: discussion, questions

I downloaded and built the source code to add a few tweaks that I couldn't add with scripting.

Are questions about the source code allowed here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Update

Now 3 years later, see [Source code questions in 2016](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2216/source-code-questions-in-2016)

---

## Unfortunately no..

It was [decided by the community](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic/6#6) *(see #4)* to make these off-topic for several reasons.

- C/C++ related questions are *way* out of the scope of what this site *is* and *should* be about.
- *Most* if not all questions that could possibly fall under this would be extremely localized…
- The site is intended *more* for artists than developers as it says in the [description](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40377/blender).

  > ... Q&A site for people who use Blender to create 3D graphics, animations, or games.

So keep it to scripting only — Python, GLSL and OSL *only* related questions are allowed to an extent if kept minimal and in relation to Blender but for anything else programming related, you are better off asking on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com), the [bf-committers](http://lists.blender.org/mailman/listinfo/bf-committers) mailing list or visiting the IRC channel `#blendercoders` on the freenode network.