# Change BSE's site description and intro section

Tags: discussion

BSE is the featured site today (yay!) That got me thinking about our site description. Why do we have the "Who use blender to create X"? Why do we care what people are creating? As long as there is a question about blender this is the site for you.

This is our current intro section (from the [tour page](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour)):

> **Blender Stack Exchange** is a question and answer site for people who use Blender to create 3D graphics, animations, or games. It's built and run *by you* as part of the [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com) network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about blender.

I purpose we remove the *"people who use Blender to create 3D graphics, animations, or games."* Not only is that unnecessary, it also is excluding a large amount of what people do with blender. But that is beside the point, there is no need to list out what you can use blender for.

How about something more along the lines of:

> **Blender Stack Exchange** is a question and answer site for people who use [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) an open source full suite 3D content creation package. This site is built and run *by you*, the users, as part of the [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com) network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about blender.

---

The site description is shown on every question page for non-logged in users and used  in other places across the network, like the sites list shown below.

[image: random question page showing the help banner]

The [sites list](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list) says:

> Q&A for people who use Blender to create 3D graphics, animations, or games

Comment: "As long as there is a question about blender this is the site for you." I'm in favor of emphasizing that, as historically that's not really been true. Questions about developing blender, for example, were originally considered off topic. I think we decided to allow them a [while ago](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2216/599), but so far not much has been asked, perhaps because we were pretty rigid about disallowing them early on.

Answer (score 6):

How about:

> **Blender Stack Exchange** is a question and answer site for everything Blender, the open source 3D and multimedia content creation package.

To include things that might not fall under "usage", like [development](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2216/599).

Comment: Keep in mind that there are other users who don't deal with 3d content at all, like compositing and video editing, or 2d animation with the Grease Pencil

Comment: "3d and multimedia" content creation package?

Comment: @cegaton Good point, I like it. Added it in, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

> **Blender Stack Exchange** For users of [Blender](https://www.blender.org/)

Comment: Still thinking about the usage on the sites list, how about *"... For users of the open source 3D creation suite [Blender](https://www.blender.org)"* (that is if they allow link like that.)

Comment: I mean we've gotten a handful of smoothie questions in the past but seems unlikely nowadays.

Comment: ... sigh. That would be for users of Blenders. My point here is to keep it short and sweet. Change to for everything blender, for lovers of blender, for q & a ... Surely a question here requires some knowledge of what blender is.  If they don't know then why not point them to blender.org and let _our creator_ (who looks like  Jeremy Clarkson lol) ..  and the team define what blender is rather than feeling the need to spin it here.