# question closed unfairly again

Tags: discussion

After a year off-site, my question promptly got closed [again](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249164/blenders-internal-mesh-representation). I assume you have read it. Now to my defense. Blender has an internal mesh representation, my app has an internal mesh representation and they are not the same. Some kind of conversion (import/export) needs to take place. Hence my question is a bona fide, import/export question of which there are a ton on this site. The reason that my question is not about blender use is wrong, I need export blender meshes, not just any meshes.

Comment: The problem is that the question you ask, _as written_ is about a comparison between bmesh and a hypothetical "better" mesh representation.  That's not an import/export question _as written_. It's probably possible to write a question where the answer is about issues that might arise from exporting bmeshes, but this is not that question.

Comment: Bubble sort is worse than quick sort. We are talking about algorithms (mesh ops), operating on a mesh representation. Performance of an algorithm can always be quantified, there can be no ambiguity.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether your question could be answered factually, and you're talking about suitability of data structures, not algorithm metrics, which isn't so easy to quantify.  The point here is that your question _as written_ isn't about Blender.  It's about comparing two data structures, one of which isn't from Blender.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think your question can be answer here for a variety of reasons.

> So, my question is: is there a "better" mesh representation than the one blender is using

I'm sure there are hundreds, each with its own advantages and disadvantages. This is neither an objective question nor a question about using Blender itself, which is what this site tends to focus on.

> The problem I am having is as follows: I would not like to mimic what blender is doing in their code in my own program

Virtually everything you do differently from Blender is by technically "not copying" it, or at the very least improving over it. This sounds like a very broad and open ended discussion, more suited for some coding or programming oriented site.

Even there "How can I do things differently" doesn't seem like a valid question that can be answered with facts.

Now source code questions [have been considered on topic here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2216/source-code-questions-in-2016), if it was focusing on some technical aspects or specific details of the implementation, but your post doesn't seem to be focusing on any data structures or how to convert them to some undisclosed format you intend to use.

A potentially acceptable question would say something along the lines of

> Bmesh uses data structure X that I need to convert to import into my app that uses Y. How can I do this?

And proceed to show some code examples. This might have a chance at some coding site, again not something we would generally deal with here.

Comment: Magnificient hand waving here, where are these hundreds of mesh representations documented? I'd like to see. Can't anyone disprove my claim that there are just a hanful of mesh representatons.