# What should our custom off-topic close reasons be?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope, close-reasons

[Custom close reasons](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/) have been live for a while now. We currently have 2 of the (3) given in use but a recent surge in questions being closed has prompted the need for a few more that are more tailored to address specific questions/close reasons instead of writing up *why* it is off-topic everytime.

Here are some guidelines to work with:

- **Keep it simple** - so new users reading these will understand, especially if they are not familiar with StackExhange.
- **Give solid reasoning** - try to have something that's not too open-ended as to open things up to a debate or retort.
- **Keep it brief** - there's no need to write a book about it so lets aim for under 500 characters, including links and other Markdown tags.
- **Give your reasoning** behind each reason - it helps to reference previous meta posts so we don't confuse users that haven't gotten the chance (or time) to peruse our meta site.

We are currently looking for close reasons pertaining to:

- <strike>Not even remotely about Blender</strike>

  > This question does not appear to be about Blender within the scope defined in the [help center](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).
- <strike>Too localized</strike>

  > This question is too localized in its current form and is unlikely to be applicable outside of a very narrow context. Consider broadening the scope of this question in order to [make it more useful](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for future users of the site.
- <strike>Bug reports</strike>

  > This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bug report and not an actual question. These should be reported to [Blender's tracker](http://www.blender.org/development/report-a-bug/) instead.
- <strike>Feature requests</strike>
- Hardware questions
- <strike>Unrelated programming questions (C/C++) etc</strike>

See [What questions should be definitely off-topic?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic) for more ideas on what is off-topic here.

Comment: We should also have a close reason to handle tutorial requests. This might normally be covered by the standard "no effort" StackExchange reason, but I think the nature of this site deserves a reason that's more clear and less frustrating to people who might not understand how their question "shows no effort."

Comment: @Matt I agree, hence the point of this post. Feel free to suggest some below.

Comment: The bug report one needs to be updated, that link goes to a 404 now that blender.org has been updated.

Comment: We should use all top three. Feature requests off-topic reason doesn't seem that necessary.

Comment: @DantheMan We want specific close reasons. Doesn't make sense to close then have to further explain why.

Comment: @iKlsR I thought there was a limit to how many off-topic reasons of 3.

Comment: @DantheMan We can ask for more. SO has like a dozen or so.

Answer (score 6):

## Tutorial Requests

This question appears to be off-topic because it requires step-by-step instructions for a process that is specific to a particular project, and/or demonstrates too little effort on the part of the asker. These kinds of problems have been well solved elsewhere and are beyond the scope of this StackExchange.

Comment: Nice, I like this one.

Comment: I agree that we need a "Tutorial Request" on-hold reason, but I think there is a big gray area on what is a tutorial. Without doubt questions like "How do I model an animate a character?" is clearly such a tut request (or maybe "Too broad"?). But what about questions like [How to make a displacement map from existing 3d geometry](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1161/how-to-make-a-displacement-map-from-existing-3d-geometry) or [Creating a curved rectangle on outside of a sphere?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5652/creating-a-curved-rectangle-on-outside-of-a-sphere)?

Comment: This has been discussed to some extent here:
http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29/what-would-be-wrong-with-tutorials-as-long-as-they-describe-a-reusable-workflow

and here:
http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62/regarding-questions-and-answers-as-tutorials

These are my main points of reference for this response.

Also, keep in mind that a question does not necessarily have to be placed on hold, closed, or even flagged at first. In many cases, it would probably be appropriate to start by adding a comment recommending improvements to the question, before flagging it.

Answer (score 4):

## Feature Requests

This question appears to be off-topic because it asks about adding features not yet in Blender. These should instead be posted on the [requests section of the blender wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Requests) or in the [bf-functionality mailing list](http://lists.blender.org/mailman/listinfo/bf-funboard).

Comment: Would this apply to people asking if such a feature exists in Blender or only if they asking for the developers to implement it?

Comment: @DantheMan See http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/177/599 "Someone can ask if a feature exists to perform a certain task, but unless its in a blender release, or already implemented to be included in the next release - I think the answer has to be NO."

Answer (score 4):

## Source code questions

This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Blender C/C++ source code.
These questions are considered outside the scope of this StackExchange as [defined in the help center](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Development questions should be asked of the developers directly instead, see the [contacting developers page of the blender wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Contact).

Answer (score 3):

## Hardware/OS questions

This questions appears to be off-topic because it is about the operating system, hardware, performance, or compatibility. These questions are considered off-topic because there is often no definitive answer, so they tend to require too much discussion to be suitable for Q&A format.  Try asking on [BlenderArtists](http://blenderartists.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?44-Technical-Support) for support instead.

Comment: [I think we can..](http://blenderartists.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?44-Technical-Support).

Comment: Should this close reason be generalized to include platform/driver related questions?

Comment: Yes, it's out of the scope of this site.

Answer (score 2):

### **Bug Reports for Code by Independent Authors**

I think there should be two different Bug report close reasons:

- One for bugs in Blender itself: that one should say "report to Blender's Bug tracker"
- One for bugs in code from other coders: that one should say "report to code author"

I think this is a very important distinction that OP needs to be aware of, because if we refer bug reports about non-Blender code to the Blender devs, they're going to get upset with us if it keeps happening.

Answer (score -1):

## Bug Reports

This can also count for technical support for things like crashes.