# Can we change the close message of the "bug report" close reason?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, close-reasons

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bug report and **not an actual question**. These should be [reported to Blender's tracker](http://developer.blender.org/) instead.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

We usually close questions which were asked buggy behavior as bug reports, regardless of whether or not the question was not phrased as a bug report, or even of the OP seemed to realize there was a bug (related: [When should a question be closed as a bug report?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/351/599)).

**TL;DR:** We get "actual questions" which should still be closed as bug reports, as they pertain to a bug (though often the OP isn't aware of this).

To reflect this, can we change the close reason to something like the following?

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is a result of a bug in blender. Bugs should be [reported to the tracker](http://developer.blender.org/). Also see [this guide](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1378/599) on how to write a useful bug report.

*Not completely happy with this phrasing, perhaps someone will have a better idea...*

Comment: The phrasing seems fine to me but with the meta post that came after this. It will have to be put on hold for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new wording as of September 30, 2015 for the bug report close reason reads:

> This question appears to be about an issue caused by a bug in Blender. These should be [reported to the official bug tracker](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1377/2217).

You can read more about the change here: [Cleaning up our custom close reasons](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/914/2217).