# Cleaning up our custom close reasons

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

For a [long time](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/584/599) our close reasons have been wanting of attention.
We've just now gotten around to making a few changes:

## Bug reports

We've decided to change the wording of this close reason, as it ended up being used not only for mis-placed reports, but also normal questions which turned out to be the result of some bug.

**Old**

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bug report and not an actual question. These should be [reported to Blender's tracker](http://developer.blender.org/) instead.

**New**

> This question appears to be about an issue caused by a bug in Blender. These should be [reported to the official bug tracker](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1377/2217).

## Tutorials

As [pointed out](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/584/599), this close reason serves effectively the same purpose as the *Too Broad* close reason. As such it has now been retired, allowing space for adding less redundant reasons in the future.

Comment: If you have any suggestions, feel free to leave a comment. We want these to be as concise as possible.

Comment: Hardware: **This is not a question about blender but a question regarding hardware recommendations**

Comment: Operating system: **This is a question about the use of the operating system and not about blender**

Comment: How about (and this was a real close reason): **"it is about a kitchen implement, not the software package."**

Comment: @David I know, because I wrote that D:

Comment: @David I think we only have one question for that. :)