# Custom Off Topic Close messages 2021 Edition

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderation

David [recently brought up again on chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57620478#57620478) the matter of our site's custom off topic messages.
This has been discussed a number of times before here on meta, but got lost to time, and nothing fruitful ever came of it.

1. [New off topic close reason](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2249/new-off-topic-close-reason)
2. [What should our custom off-topic close reasons be?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296/what-should-our-custom-off-topic-close-reasons-be)
3. [Custom off-topic close reasons: 2014 in review](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/584/custom-off-topic-close-reasons-2014-in-review)

The gist of it being that we only get three custom close images per site, we are currently only making use of two of them and should benefit from third one.

[image]

This time I plan to see it through and add myself the new message we agree on, with the approval of all mods.

Since the number of messages is limited we should use them wisely, and choose a well though out option. It is also a process that requires approval from several moderators.

[According to statistics](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=last90days) "blatantly off topic" seems to be the most commonly used custom message,  something along the lines of.

> I’m voting to close this question because it is not about using Blender.

For questions that are completely off topic and not at all about Blender itself. Like say about game engines, about other FOSS like Inkscape, or about kitchen appliances.

With this in mind what would be your suggestions for our third custom close message?

Should it be something more broad and encompassing that can be used for a broader range of closed questions, making the life of reviewers easier at the expense of a less clear message for the OP?

Or should it be something shorter and concise, for more specific cases. Should it include useful links directing the OP to where he these can be asked for most common off topic cases?

Feel free to use the answers below to suggest your preferred custom close messages.

These are the fields we have available when creating a new message:

[image]

For current site moderators you can edit site custom close messages from https://blender.stackexchange.com/admin/flags/site-specific-close-reasons
accessible through the "mod diamond" menu at the top > *Dashboard > Links* tab at the top *> Data Alteration Pages > Manage community-specific close reasons*. Other users will probably see an error page.

Comment:  looks good so far.

Answer (score 7):

I'd suggest something more encompassing and informative including links that can be used as close message for more cases.

A more generic close text that covers more situations can make the life of reviewers easier, at the potential expense of sounding more like a generic canned response for the OP.

Including useful links to help the user make his question more on topic would be encouraged.

## Close dialog option

### Brief description

Briefly describe why the question is being closed

> This question is not about Blender or asking for hardware recommendations.

### Usage guidance

Give the user guidance as to when they should select this option

> When the question doesn't seem to be strictly about using Blender or in any way related to the software, like game development, hardware recommendations or other third party software.

## Post notices

### Close description

When a post is closed with a single community-specific close reason, this message will be displayed publicly above any private guidance.

> This question doesn't seem to be about using Blender or in any way related to the software as defined in the [help center](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

### Post owner guidance

Provide meaningful actions a user can take to either get their question reopened or have a more favorable outcome in the future.

> This question was put on hold since it doesn't seem to be about using Blender as defined in the [help center](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).
>
> - For general questions about Python https://stackoverflow.com
> - For questions about game development you can use https://gamedev.stackexchange.com
> - For hardware recommendations https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com
>
> If you can, rephrase the question to make it on topic by focusing on the Blender specific part of the problem.

### Privileged user guidance

Provide guidance for users with the reopen privilege so they can constructively engage the post owner and reopen the question if appropriate.

> If you can rephrase the question to make it on topic by focusing on the Blender specific part of the problem [edit] it so it can be reopened.

Comment: I very much like where this is headed. To support this idea I counted up the custom close reasons (all that I have access to) That includes the last 90 days, and all from 2014. In 2014 we had **126** custom reasons, **68** of them were used on questions not about blender. In the last 90 days there has been **65** custom close messages written and **33** were not about blender. The second most commonly written message is about hardware recommendations, but with **8** in the last 90 days you can see it is far behind "not about Blender."

Comment: Well that settles it for me, I was worried it was not the most common reason, but I guess this clears any doubts. Good point about hardware, I included that in the OP messages as well, and make this more versatile

Comment: looks good to me, no objections here :)

Comment: Looks good to me as well.

Comment: Proposal has been submitted with a few minor adjustments to fit within character count constraints. It now awaits review by other fellow moderators. Thanks for the feedback