# Is this off topic?

Tags: discussion

[Declare a global variable in a Blender session](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6031/declare-a-global-list)

I'm still not quite sure what the scope of our site is. Would this be considered off-topic? It seems like it's mostly just Python. If not, why? I'm interested in understanding the principles/reasons so that I can apply them better.

Comment: Pure python questions are off-topic but as long as it is related to use in Blender in any way. It's fine.

Comment: In this case, the question is about Python scripts sharing data within Blender, how scripts interact within Blender is a little confusing to many new devs so, I think this is fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you taken a look here: [What questions should be definitely off-topic?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic)?

We have a clear list of what is allowed and what is isn't. You *can* ask Python related questions here so long as they are about Blender + Python.

Comment: Ah, must have overlooked this one somehow.