# Can you ask too many Questions?

Tags: discussion

My question is if someone can ask to many questions on this site or are they allowed to ask as many questions as they want?

Comment: My opinion is that - everyone can ask as many questions as they want, as long as they are good and contribute to the site.

Comment: If your question has been answered accept the proper answer as such

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [Is there a limit on how many questions I can ask?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4359/is-there-a-limit-on-how-many-questions-i-can-ask).

> A user may ask only...
>
> - [50 questions over any 30-day period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89217/50-question-per-month-limit)
> - [six questions over any 24-hour period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90470/increase-the-limit-of-6-questions-in-24-hours)
> - one question over any 30-second period
> - [users with less than 125 reputation can only post questions every 20 minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66844)
>
> The 30-day limit was introduced on 29 April 2011, and at the moment of
>   writing it only applies to Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super
>   User. Beware that deleting existing questions will probably not
>   circumvent this limit, and [may actually make things
>   worse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86982/should-i-avoid-deleting-my-questions).
>
> The 30-second and "only post questions every 20 minutes" limits are
>   anti-spam/bot measures.

So in accordance with this, you can ask as many questions as you want, as long as they are all about blender and not [**off-topic**](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic).
It's better to have several unique questions as opposed to a single post containing many. The idea is to keep it simple and organized so others can easily find information down the line.