# Is it okay to ask questions about Blender related tasks?

Tags: discussion, scope

I asked myself if Blender SE is meant to answer questions that don't ask for help with the software but around the software. A specifc question would be

> Is there a central place to host plugins I have developed?

As this doesn't really ask for help inside Blender itself but rather about interacting with it's community I wondered if such questions are allowed here. I personally believe that this does fit our scope because it helps `people who use Blender to create 3D graphics, animations, or games.`

I want to stress that I think about questions where people search for *ways to get in touch with the Blender community*, not where the question is how to achieve X on some site Y - for example BlenderNation.

I want to point out that e.g. [this question](/questions/1190/best-place-to-put-feature-requests) is well received and not about Blender's inside at all - contrary to what is pointed out [in this meta post](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6/2251) see #8.

So, are we allowed to post questions about getting in touch with the Blender community?

Answer (score 3):

A question such as your example would be closed as off topic.

BSE is for blender, and problems around blender. A broad question simply asking about a hosting location falls too far away from blender and the scope of this site.

In a very broad general statement I would say that questions about "getting in touch with the Blender community" are off topic.

Answer (score 2):

The BSE community has compiled a list of Blender resources / links, if someone asks about the blender community or ecosystem we'll probably close the question as off topic and point them to that: [Resources for Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender)

There's never a need for us to be impolite about closing a question, sufficient information can be exchanged even with the question closed. In the end usually even if the question is outside of out scope there is some answer or hints of where to look for information.