# Is this an acceptable place to ask for feedback on a sculpt? If not what would be a better place?

Tags: discussion

Feedback from people who know what they are doing would be helpful in getting better, but I do not know a great place to ask for that feedback.

Comment: Generally the point of meta is for discussing the site, if that's what your question is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No BSE is not for Critiques. (See point six [What questions should be definitely off-topic?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6/2217)) Any question like you described would get closed as off topic.

You could try in our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm) there is almost always somebody there, but I dont know how much help you will get.

A much better place for feedback is on blender artists. There is a entire thread for [Focused Critiques](http://blenderartists.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?26-Focused-Critiques).

Answer (score 0):

Try CG Stack Extchange, I guess that would be the right place to do so, since I've seen a post there requesting feedback, and nobody seems to object: https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/

Still make sure to ask the right question, as in asking, what do you think is missing? Or should I do it this way? Rather than How do you like it?

Comment: On Computer Graphics Stack Exchange a request for an artistic review would be off topic, but a review of code that produces or works with models could be on topic depending on the context. A review of a hand sculpted model would be off topic. As a rough guide, if you're *writing* software your question is likely to be on topic, while if you're *using* software it is likely off topic. Research and algorithm questions are also on topic though, so for specific details see the Computer Graphics [on topic page](http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @trichoplax http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/2556/what-physical-properties-are-lacking-to-keep-this-3d-scene-from-looking-like-a

Comment: I thought that might be the example you were thinking of - it's a good way of seeing that the scope isn't obvious. In that case it's asking about which physical effects need to be included, rather than asking for a review of just the model. Some answers do include criticism of the model though, since that's part of what breaks the realism.

Comment: I think that the type of review question that the author of this meta question has in mind would be off topic, but Computer Graphics may well be an appropriate site for some of the people who find this meta question in future. Exactly what is on topic can't be easily summed up in comments, but there's the on topic page and also [Computer Graphics chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26589/the-cornell-box) for anyone with further queries.

Comment: Exactly it's a feedback request of a specific aspect concerning an artistic opinion based matter