# How should I flag tutorial requests?

Tags: discussion, support

I recently came across a question that is nothing but a request for a tutorial. I looked into flagging it, but I couldn't decide what flag to use.

Off topic gives me the choices of bug report, too localized, blatantly off topic, and belongs on another SE. The closest one there would be too localized, but that doesn't feel quite right.

The question is certainly not unclear. I wouldn't say it's opinion based either. Too broad perhaps?

Is there a community consensus about how to flag these?

Comment: Localized is a good goto if you're unsure I should think. How many people want to model and texture a realistic big bird for example.

Comment: @iKlsR I for one done. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I will talk to the other mods and see if we can get a close reason something like

> Blatantly off-topic (this question has nothing to do with blender, or is [off topic](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6/2217) for this site).

Until then you can, vote to close with a custom reason such as "This is a tutorial request." Or in your case flag to close. *Flag* > *should be closed...* > *off-topic because...* > *Other*.

Comment: While I agree with having a tutorial close reason (though it will need very careful thought put into phrasing and definition, as IMO some kinds of broader questions are good), I don't think a "blatantly off topic" reason is a good idea. Yes, [some questions](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18665/599) fall under such a category (and no other), but I think close reasons should always give a *reason* for closing (besides "this question is bad and needs to die"). Corner cases where no preset reasons apply are what the "other" option is for.

Comment: I'm not understanding how your suggested close reason is better than those that already exist. Wouldn't it just be easier to have a really obvious 'this is a tutorial request' reason?

Comment: @RayMairlot My thought for that wording was that we have no current CV reasons to close questions that are on [this list](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/6/2217) (except for bugs). While a "This is a tutorial request" reason defiantly is clear, I thought making it broader would be more useful in more cases.

Comment: I see, I didn't realise you were aiming for something broader. In that case, I don't think "this question has nothing to do with blender" is fitting as some of the question types on that list *are* to do with blender, they're just not *good* questions (tutorial requests) or questions that can easily be answered (compiling blender).

Comment: The problem is that there is no reason named "Other". There are the four that I listed. Perhaps something to do with my rep not being high enough for some flags yet, or possibly reviews and flags look slightly different..

Comment: @RayMairlot We have limited close reasons so we have to make them as wide as their scope phrase can cover while still toting some specificity. There *has* been a gap for a while and I think outright saying a question is off-topic and linking to our meta is an ok way to proceed. The phrasing can be perfected but the idea is a good one.