# Add a "Closing > Off-Topic > Not about Blender" reason

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

There seem to be a considerable amount of questions that pop up from time to time that are off topic because they are not specifically about Blender.

They are often about 'accompanying' software ( like GIMP, Inkscape, Photoshop), third party game engines (Unity, Unreal, etc), problems importing file formats in other software or 3D packages (3DS Max, Cinema4D, Maya, etc.), or feature requests.

Lately even general Python programming, simply lost users from other software like Sketchup, or Cinema4D, or some times totally unrelated.

Here are a few random examples of late

- https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66731/python-debuggin
- https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66708/blender-3d-interactive-car-model-for-online
- [How to make custom logo for published bge game](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63768/how-to-make-custom-logo-for-published-bge-game/64235#64235)
- [Can someone make a plugin for .nif like 3ds max has](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51544/can-someone-make-a-plugin-for-nif-like-3ds-max-has/51549#51549)

These don't quite fit in any of the other Off-Topic reasons, and might happen often enough to warrant adding the option there by default.

What do you think, would it be worth adding the pre-defined off topic option? Is it even doable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes** I whole heartily agree.  In fact we have talked about [this](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/584/2217) [before](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/914/2217), yet we never got around to changing all three of our custom messages.

I too think that a "not about blender" or something like that would be useful.
I even suggested something slimier before, [here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2183/2217). (But that idea was met with a good bit of resistances, so some other wording will have to be worked out.)

Here is the same wording as I suggested before (just to sure up discussion):

> Blatantly off-topic (this question has nothing to do with blender, or is [off topic](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6/2217) for this site).

Comment: That'd be a welcome addition. Also, for *Opinion Based* closed questions perhaps include a link to a forum like Blender artists or alike :)