# what to do with Yes or No questions

Tags: discussion

Often (especially in the unanswered list) there seem to be question which are seemingly answered with a *yes* or *no*.

I'm not talking about [not answerable](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2287/30849) question, buts valid question which appear to in scope, (almost) an generally [valid](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) questions.

This is a [good, relevant question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90455/render-only-nodes-that-change), but the answer could be a simple "No, Blender doesn't have this feature." But according to [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) "don’t do that" is understandably discouraged. Should the answer be unanswered untill Blender gets this feature or a valid workaround?

Even worse with "Can I do A with method B in Blender?". The answer would be "Yes." and since the OP already is aware of the method, he is probably able to do it without a tutorial answer.

In a very specific context of [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90455/render-only-nodes-that-change), [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101780/how-can-i-do-an-advanced-bake-in-the-blender-game-engine) and [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107331/how-can-i-access-onedrive-from-within-blender) question: Should they get bumped untill someone comes along with a crazy workaround? (The last one even already mentions the workaround in the question itself.)

More context (yeah, my own stupid questions):
[Yes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70910/animation-nodes-loop-performance) > "Nothing to worry about, this doesn't affect performance that much."
Yes  > "This is the best workflow, there isn't anything faster."
[No](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75000/update-microdisplacements-in-render-preview) and [No](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75000/update-microdisplacements-in-render-preview) > "Blender doesn't have this feature (yet)."

Note, that in the *No* cases, a future answer like "*Blender 2.8 has gotten this feature now.*" is not that useful, since the question was about the workflow **not** working. At the same time, a missing feature is not a bug. Or my three question have been closed as *too localized* as well, I seemed to think others could benefit from the as well.

Comment: If OP knows the method and still feels the need to ask a question, they are probably coming from another software, in which case some elaboration on the "how" still seems in order. In the case of a "no such feature" answer, one could elaborate on the "why not" or the "when will it" questions. I find it hard to imagine a realistic question to which there is absolutely *no* useful (even if peripheral) information which could be added to its answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should the answer be unanswered until Blender gets this feature or a valid workaround?

It is perfectly acceptable to answer that Blender doesn't yet have said feature or just leave it. A helpful workaround if possible would be great as well. For example - [Is there a way to acces external .blend file's data with python script?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2411/12)

> Even worse with "Can I do A with method B in Blender?". The answer would be "Yes." ...

I tend to find that if a potential answer can't meet the minimum required characters then the question itself might warrant some looking at to see if it itself is on-topic or useful to anyone else really. So if your judgement deems the question to require minimal effort for OP to figure out themselves *(as in simply pressing a button or two and seeing the result)* and can be condensed to a simple yes or no, you can leave a comment and these might be falling under the localized close category and could potentially be flagged as well.

> This question is too localized in its current form and is unlikely to be applicable outside of a very narrow context. ***Consider broadening the scope of this question in order to make it more useful for future users of the site.***

---

In addition to the specific questions you pointed to I would go with

1. It's not possible currently in Blender, you could say that and that would be fine.
2. Also not possible, fine to say that as well. Would also be worth mentioning that the game engine will be gone in the next major release.
3. The last one is a bit borderline but it seems there isn't a better solution available, would reaffirm their workaround and leave it at that for now, also seems that they could just map the cache location to a bookmark as a suggestion.

For your questions, I agree with your judgement on those, I would also just leave it if there is really nothing to say. Here is an example of a question that had no definite answer for some 5 years. [Will Cycles eventually replace Blender Internal?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/291/12). An answer can always be updated. It's also worth noting that the community bot will bump dormant stuff to the front page over time.