# Where would be a good location to post a Blender Addon request/idea?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I have a pretty good idea for a blender addon I figured I should throw out into the addon developing community. Would Blender Meta be the place to do this? Or the Blender Surface Site? Or should I use a site other than Stack Exchange?

Comment: PS the [meta-tag:feature-request] tag is for feature requests for the site, not blender.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "Blender Surface Site" but no the meta, nor the main site would not be the correct place to post that. See point 5 in the [off topic list](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6/2217).

You could try on [blender artists](https://blenderartists.org/forum/), or if you happen to find somebody who is interested, in [our chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm).

Comment: By surface site I simply meant the main site

Comment: Isn't there an idea site somewhere, blender right or something like that?

Comment: @iKlsR There is http://rightclickselect.com/ but that is about suggesting features for blender, not add-ons.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately ideas for addons are a dime a dozen; everyone has a million requests for addons and features, but comparatively (very) few people know how to actually code them.

Of those even less are willing to just make an addon for a "random bright idea" for free.

My advice to you is: just let it go. If you really  must you can dump it in the bloated feature request bucket that is http://rightclickselect.com if it makes you feel any better.