# What is the proper action for a question that requests links to tutorials

Tags: discussion, questions

Quite often we get the following question: *Can I get recommendations or links for tutorials on such and such topic?*

This is not about requests to make custom made tutorials, but explicitly looking only for links to existing tutorials in the internet.

A question like this not only yields link-only answers, but there is no way to mark it as correct or accepted, on top of being strictly opinion-based (and that is not mentioning that the quality of the "tutorials" that are linked will be all over the spectrum)

There was a [proposed question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86198/blender-tutorials) to address this, and got shot down.

So, instead of telling the OP that this site is not a ["I'll google it for you"](http://www.letmegooglethat.com/?q=Link+to+blender+tutorials) kind service, what is the proper way to deal with such questions?

Close them as off topic?

Too broad?

Opinion based?

Just ignore them?

Try to explain to the OP that this is not the kind of site to ask?

Comment: Also see https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic/6#6, our #1 OT reason, close these. There is a message specific for them.

Answer (score 6):

#### Vote to close as off topic.

Then if you feel so inclined, explain to the OP why asking for links to tutorials is off topic.

BSE is not a google this for me service. That type of post is bad for a few reasons.

1. links brake. (See [blender's tutorial page](https://www.blender.org/support/tutorials/))
2. It can *quickly* become outdated.
3. Does not fit in with the SE system

Like you mention, these types of questions would be asking for link only answers, a no-no right there.

---

Now Like we did with the [resources for blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15355/2217) list, (suspend the rules for one, and only one aggregate post) I suppose if the community is so inclined we could have a tutorial list. Not unlike the one you [linked to](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/86198/2217).

Yet having a tutorial list would not really solve the problem of *"Find me a tutorial to make an awesome looking purple sports car (like a Lamborghini but not as short) a convertible carbon fiber hard top, also it has to have two chrome exhaust pipes"* type of questions, those we should still close as off topic.

Comment: So I can't post a *do this for me* "question"?