# Do you know of any trustworthy blender tutorial forums?

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette

I was wondering if you know of a trustworthy blender tutorial forum, as in with tutorials that are up-to-date and idiot proof?

I don't want to ask questions on Blender stack that are not acceptable for the site.

Thanks and sorry if I "put my foot in it" again.

Comment: Blender.Stackexchange definitely isn't the right place to ask these questions as it's asking for tutorials. However I don't quite think there are any sites for that. General recommendation - try BlenderArtists.org, but the most useful is use tutorials from known tutorial creators (BlenderGuru, CreativeShrimp, BlenderDiplom, BlenderHD etc) and search engine to find the rest from what you want

Comment: Try Blender cloud. Not free, but trustworthy.

Comment: Here's a [list of resources](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15355/599), if you haven't found it already

Comment: Thank you everyone <3

Answer (score 2):

As stated above, questions asking for links are discouraged. This has been discussed here: [What is the proper action for a question that requests links to tutorials](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2380/1853)