# Why is this website designed so horribly?

Tags: discussion

I could literally go on for days about the problems with this specific forum website and its inability to provide even a modicum of helpful answers, so instead of being specific lets be general. Why is this website so garbage. It doesn't seem to ever offer any useful help that hasn't already been done better on YouTube, and when people do offer advice it's usually not even addressing the issue the original questioner asked. Then to top it off you can't even rate these garbage answers from idiots unless you trudge through the aforementioned swamp of awful answers posted up by people who don't know what they're talking about.

Comment: The search here is pretty awful.  What it IS good at is getting into google search results, for better or for worse.  As an intermediate user there was a lot of good information here, and it was frequently surfaced when I needed it.

Comment: Could you please cite some examples? it's a participative website, so everyone responds in the limits of their competence, plus you're free to come and help

Comment: Without concrete examples, this rant is useless and will not help make the site any better.

Answer (score 14):

First of all, **if you have a question** about using Blender as defined in the [help center](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), then please [***ask a question***](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Please be on topic, there is a comprehensive list of things that are off topic that should be avoided [here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic).

Make every effort to be as clear as you can be, and do your very best to communicate exactly what your problem is and what your goals are. Include images, explanatory text of what have tried, what you want to accomplish, what isn't working, and anything else you can think of that would help someone provide the best quality answer you would hope to receive.

Understand that if someone reading doesn't understand, they may prod for more information, and at times someone may edit your post in an effort to make things more readable, or help with site organization (if it's a wall of text, or has many misspellings, has incorrect tags for the question, etc). *It's normal*, and shouldn't be taken badly. *(You can always revert an edit if you strongly disagree with it, although most are done in the spirit of making improvements)*.

---

As you have noticed by now, this site is [much different](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour) than most others out there, but it has benefits to the way that it works.

This site is intended to be focused on Q&A, not to cater to conversational wading through pages of unrelated topics to a question before maybe reaching a clue to the answer.

Understand this regarding those who answer questions..

### Everyone here who answers a question is volunteering their own free time to try to help other users such as you.

---

So, keeping this in mind, understand that the quality of a question also ***depends on you***, the asker in many cases.

- Are you able or making an effort to communicate your problem?
- Are you responding to questions asked in the comments if more information is needed in order to answer (editing to add more information if requested, things like that)?
- Are you sharing the information we need to answer the question?
- Is your problem an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)?

---

To your immediate question,

Is the site perfect in design? No. Are all the thousands of answers correct? Probably not, *but try giving people the benefit of the doubt*. We all miss one or two.

In practice however, it's generally faster to get an answer here than wasting time reading about things unrelated to the original topic as tends to happen in many forums.

This never happens here... [image]

---

***To summarize, instead of complaining about what you don't like about the site,***

## Help improve it.

#### Ask [good questions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and write [good answers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 9):

First of all this site is not, and has never been, a forum, but a question and answers site, run by people who volunteer their time and experience.

There are many users with different levels of expertise, from varied age groups, cultures, economies, and educational backgrounds. The beauty of this site is that everybody is welcome to contribute, and we can all learn from each other.

Some users might better communicators than others, but keep in mind that dealing with language, math, geometry, time, space, and other abstract and complex notions is not something all of us can do easily. Being patient, understanding and excercising empathy and respect is the only way to help each other out.

Some of us are actual humans, and as such prone to make mistakes.

It is clear that pleasing everyone is not possible, some users might find this site useful, others clearly won't. If you are among the second group, you don't have to use the site and are free to find one that fulfills your needs.

If you decide to stay, help us make things better.